# Cordova iOS platform images not visible

Tags: ios, image, cordova, url

iOS cordova application has a tab bar at the bottom with background images. These images work perfectly fine in iOS 9 and iOS 10 with cordova 3.5.0,but in iOS 11.x the background images are not visible so I tried upgrading the cordova to 4.5.3 with all the required plug-ins. But that doesn't seem to work.

[In iOS 11.2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HLUQh.png)

[In iOS 9](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EZxEN.png)

Answer (score 0):

I could figure it out myself, the problem was because of the higher iOS version, image hidden property was being set to true, which I had to set to false for always, independent of OS versions.